# Typescript/Node: Src folder is not generated while building app

Tags: node.js, typescript

My project folder directory is like this

```
  + build
  + node_modules
  + server
     + config
     + api
     + database
     + ts-model
     - server.ts
  gitignore
  app.js
  package.json
  tsconfig.ts
```

My tsconfig.ts file is as follows

```
{
   "compilerOptions": {
   "module": "none",
   "target": "es2016",
   "outDir": "build",
   "noImplicitAny": true,
   "noImplicitReturns": true,
   "noImplicitThis": true
 },
 "include:": [
 "server/**/*.ts"
 ],
 "exclude": [
 "node_modules"
 ]
}
```

Issue is whenever i do npm run build, my build folder doesn't maintain folder structure.
My build folder should contain build>>server>>foldersInsideServer but it is actually build>>foldersInsideServer

```
  + build
     + config
     + api
     + database
     + ts-model
     - server.ts
```

I have seen a behavior that whenever I create another folder called "test" and put empty ts file inside, that time build generates like this

```
+build
   +server
   +test
```

But as soon as i delete test folder then it again stops generating server folder but shows folders inside server. How can we solve this issue without creating another folder with empty file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `"rootDir": "./"` to your `tsconfig.json`.

From the TypeScript [wiki](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#why-does---outdir-moves-output-after-adding-a-new-file):

> `--outDir` specifies the "root" directory of the output. The compiler needs a "root" directory in the source to mirror into the output
>   directory. If `--rootDir` is not specified, the compiler will compute
>   one; this is based on a common path calculation, which is the longest
>   common prefix of all your input files. Obviously this changes with
>   adding a new file to the compilation that has a shorter path prefix.
>
> To ensure the output does not change with adding new files specify
>   `--rootDir` on the command-line or in your tsconfig.json